# Standard Day Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My DataFrame looks like this

```
  UserId   Date  Time ObservationValue
1     10 Jan 01 10:00              200
2     10 Jan 01 11:30              120
3     10 Jan 02 08:00               50
4     10 Jan 03 05:30               45
```

I wanted to plot a standard day chart in R for each userid
X axis is Time
Y axis is ObservationValue

Am able to scatter plot all these points
But I am unable to differentiate the different dates in the scatter plot of points

Hence I wanted a line for each DATE in the graph
i.e. For UserId 10
Jan 01 must be plotted as a line
Jan 02 must be plotted as a line
both preferably in a different color.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(DataFrame, aes(Time, ObservationValue, color=Date)) + geom_line()
```

or if you want different UserIds in different plots:

```
ggplot(DataFrame, aes(Time, ObservationValue, color=Date)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~UserId)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a plot for a specific UserId, you can also use:

```
ggplot(DataFrame[DataFrame&UserId==10,], aes(Time, ObservationValue, color=Date)) + 
geom_line()
```